# Will an empty __init__.py interfere with a direct import and cause an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Some code has been refactored to make imports direct and there is a bit of a mess with reverted commits etc.. I am getting an `ImportError` and don't understand the Python import system well enough to know why. Have spent a long time looking at comparisons between branches etc but just can't find what it is..

Given the following directory structure,

```
our_project/
    __init__.py
    directory1/
        __init__.py
        file1.py
        file2.py
        file3.py
    directory2/
        __init__.py
        file3.py
        file4.py
        file5.py
    directory3/
        __init__.py
        file6.py
        file7.py
        file8.py
```

All the `__init__.py` 's are empty except the one in the `our_project/` directory which has some code in it.

Would the following at the top of `directory3/file7.py` work, and not cause an `ImportError`:

```
from out_project.directory1.file1 import my_function
```

Or do you need to write

`from our_project.directory1 import my_function` ?

It just feels as if this empty `__init__.py` is somehow interfering with things..

Comment: you don't have a `directory1` in the directory where you have `file7.py`. Try `from ..directory1.file1 import my_function`

Comment: This should work fine. If you see unexpected behaviour, you'll need to mention that behaviour. That is, show the full traceback of the `ImportError`.

Comment: Sorry, you are right about the dots. Fixed the paths

Comment: You've changed the question. `from ..directory1.file1 import my_function` was perfectly fine.

Comment: Really? I thought I just wrote the full path rather than an abbreviated path as you might write` /home/folder1/folder2` in Linux rather than `../folder2` if you were sitting in a different folder within folder1 next to folder2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top-level package suggested by your folder layout is `our_project`. That means the folder containing it should be in the Python search path.

Then you can do absolute imports from anywhere with `from our_project.directory1.file1 import my_function`.

From the `my_project.directory3.file7` module, you could instead use a relative import, `from ..directory1.file1 import my_function`.

The relative import might not work though if you're running `file7.py` as a script (with e.g. `python file7.py` on the command line). It's generally a bad idea to run scripts that are in a package by filename, as the interpreter won't be able to tell where they're supposed to be put in the package hierarchy. Instead, use `python -m our_project.directory4.file7` to run the module by its absolute name.

Here is an link to the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) which has a nice tutorial where all of it is explained.

Comment: Thanks, well your answer alleviates my main concern, which was that the `__init__.py` in `directory3/` somehow forces you to import from the directory rather than directly from the file

Answer (score 2):

The **init**.py files are just there to tell python to treat that directory as a python package so i believe how you would import depends on which packages is installed on the system (it searches you PYTHONPATH to find installed packages/modules). If just the our_project package in your example is installed you would need to import like

```
 from our_package.directory1.file1 import my_function
```

You could also use an relative import which would work regardless of what is installed

```
  from .directory1.file1 import my_function
```

The documentation on packages is here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Info on the module search path is here:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path